# when I use spring-boot-websocket , there are many broken pipe , how can I avoid this error and why it's happened

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I am writing a web-socket server by spring-web-socket, but I found many Broken pipes in error log, I hope someone tells me why this error happens, how can I avoid it.

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:315) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:612) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:532) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:347) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:289) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:748) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:701) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:691) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:494) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:309) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar!/:9.0.17]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

this is server error info, and the client is html5, what causes this error, I have no clue, help me,
thanks.

Comment: Usually this is caused because the client doesn't have the connection anymore. Do you have a heartbeat in place?